# Veterans Affairs API OpenID Connect in Postman

Tags: authorization, postman, openid, openid-connect

I am trying to verify a veteran's status using the Veteran Affairs' API in Postman. 
They use OpenID for authorization and authentication.

They state your application has to do a redirect to  `https://dev-api.va.gov/oauth2/authorization` with the proper data.

I've been trying but I keep getting this issue in my Postman console:
`invalid_client`

Has anyone done an OpenID Connect flow in Postman?

This is from the VA's documentation:

```
Your application will need to redirect the Veteran's browser to our OpenID authorization server with a request like this:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://dev-api.va.gov/oauth2/authorize?
  response_type=code
  &scope=openid%20profile%20email%20offline_access
  &client_id=s6BhdRkqt3
  &state=af0ifjsldkj
  &redirect_uri=<yourRedirectURL>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Postman right now doesn't support OpenID, there is a feature request for it.

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6717

What I can do however is create a tool for me to get the Authorization code and then use that to get the ID token and/or Access token and continue with the normal OAuth2.0 flow in Postman with a Bearer Token.

Comment: I created a Postman collection to explore their API: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/1034536/SzfCV6TH?version=latest
However, the easiest way to get an access token that you can then paste into this collection is using the VA API clients (I used docker) and edit it so it prints the access token in the console.